# How to calculate the charge distribution at the ortho/para or meta sites of a substituted benzene ring

Tags: aromatic-compounds, software, cheminformatics

I've modelled a few substituted benzene rings in avogadro and retrieved the partial charges of each atom; I've tried to sum the partial charges of the carbon and hydrogen atoms at the ortho/para and meta sites to see the overall partial charge at that site but results don't make sense as the para site always ends up being 0.

How can I calculate the charge at the sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary: The method used does not handle π-conjugation**

The partial charges in Avogadro (and many other software programs) are assigned by default by the Gasteiger-Marsili scheme†

Importantly, while the Gastieger charges are fairly good for atomic partial charges of organic-ish molecules, they're unlikely to reproduce effects in conjugated systems very well.

> A method is presented for the rapid calculation of atomic charges in σ-bonded and nonconjugated π-systems. Atoms are characterized by their orbital electronegativities. In the calculation only the connectivities of the atoms are considered. Thus only the topology of a molecule is of importance.

My suggestion is to use some type of quantum chemical calculation, e.g.:

- NWChem
- OpenMOPAC
- ORCA
- (etc.)

Even semiempirical quantum chemical methods (e.g. PM7) will allow you to assign charges based on the quantum electrostatic potential around the molecule. They'll be *much* more accurate at the trends you want.

† ["Iterative Partial Equalization of Orbital Electronegativity - A Rapid Access to Atomic Charges," *Tetrahedron*, Vol. 36, pp. 3219-3228, **1980**.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-4020(80)80168-2)